# React JS - stop infinite scroll at the end of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flickr

I have this simple react app,  where I fetch the Flickr public feed. So, I can scroll to the end of the page and new content is going to show. So I would like to scroll until there is nothing else new, and the app stops trying to load more content, because it has reached the last item of the list, which is not happening if I try to scroll (you can see that on the loading message). How can I fix this?

Check the code below:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import $ from "jquery";

import PhotoListItem from "./photoListItem";

import "./photoApp.css";

export default class PhotoApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      photoList: [],
      searchTerm: "cyanotype",
      items: 8,
      loadingState: false,
      loadingMessage: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPhotoList();
    this.onInfiniteScroll();
  }

  /* get data from Flickr public feed */
  getPhotoList = () => {
    const flickrApiPoint =
      "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&tags=" +
      this.state.searchTerm;

    try {
      $.ajax({
        url: flickrApiPoint,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { format: "json" },
        success: function(data) {
          this.setState({ photoList: data.items });
        }.bind(this)
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  /* code for infinite scroll */
  onInfiniteScroll = () => {
    this.refs.iScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (
        this.refs.iScroll.scrollTop + this.refs.iScroll.clientHeight >=
        this.refs.iScroll.scrollHeight - 20
      ) {
        this.loadMoreItems();
      }
    });
  };

  /* code for infinite scroll */
  loadMoreItems = () => {
    if (this.state.loadingState) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      loadingState: true,
      loadingMessage: "Loading photos..."
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        items: prevState.items + 8,
        loadingState: false,
        loadingMessage: "No more photos to show."
      }));
    }, 1000);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.photoList)
    return (
      <div className="appContainer" ref="iScroll">
        <div className="appHeader">
          <h1 className="headerTitle">
            Welcome to Flickr Alternative Photography Feed!
          </h1>
        </div>

        <div className="gridContainer">
          {this.state.photoList
            .slice(0, this.state.items)
            .map((photo, index) => {
              const author = photo.author.split(/"/)[1];
              const authorLink = photo.description.split(/"/)[1];
              const description = photo.description.split(/"/)[13];
              return (
                <PhotoListItem
                  key={index}
                  url={photo.media.m}
                  photoLink={photo.link}
                  title={photo.title}
                  author={author}
                  authorLink={authorLink}
                  description={description}
                  tags={photo.tags}
                />
              );
            })}
        </div>

        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.loadingState ? (
            <p className="loading">{this.state.loadingMessage}</p>
          ) : (
            <p className="loading">{this.state.loadingMessage}</p>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-glitter-j0d2y)

Thank you!

Comment: Why does that very last bit of code (the `<React.Fragments>...` bit) have a ternary in which both cases do the exact same thing?

Comment: They show a different message when it's true or false @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: No, they don't: they are the _exact same code_, so `this.state.loadingMessage` might be different, but that is entirely irrelevant when it comes to the JSX you've written: in both cases, the exact same code gets run, so that ternary shouldn't be there.

Comment: Okay, got it! What do you suggest then? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Yes, I understood. Which is the best practice for this case, then? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Just replace the ternary with `<p className="loading">{this.state.loadingMessage}</p>`, so you get `<React.Fragment><p className="loading">{this.state.loadingMessage}</p></React.Fragment>`, but I'm not sure I understand why you'd even wrap that in a fragment, paragraphs are perfectly legal inside a div, so: just generate `<p className="loading">{this.state.loadingMessage}</p>`?

Comment: It makes sense what you explained, it's simpler the way you said! :) @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the item that you've loaded exceeds your items in your ajax request

```
  /* code for infinite scroll */
  loadMoreItems = () => {
    // hasMore = data.items.length (you may want to rename this more appropriately)
    if (this.state.loadingState || (this.state.items > this.state.hasMore)) {
      // Do not load if there's no more items
      return;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, I was almost there! Thank you, @Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Your `onInfiniteScroll` doesn't have any code right now that checks whether it *should* load more items, it just blindly does. So: at the end of `getPhotoList` you probably want to check whether that's the last page of results and if so, do a `setState({ exhausted: true })` or something similar, so you can check that value in your `onInfiniteScroll` and *not* do anything if you see `this.state.exhausted === true`.